# Did the Ancients in Stargate have a religion?

Tags: stargate

I've really only watched Stargate: Atlantis, so I don't know if this is brought up in SG1 or Universe.

Are the Ancients ever described as being religious, or worshipping any deities?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ancient Alterans didn't have a religious faith but they did worship science. That was the entire crux of their argument with the forces of the Ori who eventually forced them out of their home galaxy.

> **ALTERAN WOMAN TWO:** ***We believe in the systematic understanding of the physical world through observation and experimentation,*** through
>   argument and debate, but, most of all, freedom of will. I will not
>   compromise the fundamental tenets of my devotion in order to preserve
>   it.
>
> <sub><sup>[Stargate: The Ark of Truth](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Stargate:_The_Ark_of_Truth_Transcript)</sup></sub>

Eventually both branches of the Alteran people ascended. The Alterans in the Milky Way became the Ancients and the Ori founded their own religion.

Comment: There's also the Destiny which was investigating a deep structure in space time that might have indicated some intelligent hand behind the universe, IIRC?

Comment: @starpilotsix - Yeah. But we never found out what it was.

Comment: @Glen_b - It says tenants in the script :-)

Comment: @Valorum Wow. I withdraw my objection ... but facepalm with both hands.

Comment: You don't really "worship" science unless you're doing it wrong. Religion is basically without exception a matter of faith and belief. Science is all about evidence and theory.